# Compiling Typescript module to AMD but not wrapping result in object eg. Foo.Foo

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, module, typescript, amd

I am working on converting part of a large Backbone application to use Typescript. Some of the core js files have been converted to Typescript and are referenced by other non-TS js files.

Before we converted our requirejs modules would be of the form:

View.js

```
define([backbone, deps...], function (backbone, deps...) {
    return backbone.View.extend({
        render: function () {...}
    });
});
```

Which in the consuming code we could do:

```
define([View, ...], function (View,....) {
     var view = new View({...});
     view.render();
});
```

Using Typescript external modules and exports I can compile a file containing a Typescript class to AMD but the code generated sets a property on an exports object as the results which means consuming code looks like this now, given the file name is View.js:

```
var view = new View.View();
```

This is annoying and also means we can't maintain backward compatibility with the legacy non-TS code without changes (though minor). Is there anyway to get around this?

EDIT: 
Relevant generated code (the define callback)

```
function (require, exports) {

    var Backbone = require('backbone');

    var View = (function (_super) {
        __extends(View, _super);
        function View(options) {
            _super.call(this, options);
        }
    })(Backbone.View);
    exports.View = View;
}
```

The aim is to have some core components in typescript so that we can use TS going forward, and have other older libraries require the completed js components.

Comment: did you put `View.render()` INSIDE a module/namespace?

Comment: View.js is consumed in a normal requirejs module that is not Typescript compiled.

Comment: In View.ts View is a class eg. export class View {}

Comment: Actually bad example I'll change it to reflect more closely our use case for View.

Comment: It would be good to see your generated code/ ts files

Comment: I think you should use `export = ViewClass` in your views. Then you should be able to use `import View = require("someView"); var view = new View()`

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-export-

Comment: That's correct Sami! Cheers